# Keep textbox input values OR prevent page reload

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Im using a filter-function to sort my listbox. The problem is that everytime i using the filter-function(string in a textbox and a button to make them filter on the string), the page reload and i need to fill in the 4 textboxes again, that i already have filled in before the reload.

Is there any good solution for this?

```
        .on("click", "#search", function () {

            var searchString = $("#searchString").val();
            location.href = '/Meeting/Meeting?searchString=' + searchString

        });

 <input class="form-control" type="text" id="searchString" />

 <button type='button' id="search" class="btn btn-default">submit</button>
```

Comment: Can you clarify? The _"quick"_ answer to this (as in all "prevent page reload" questions) is "Well, then do `Ajax/Xhr`", instead of what you're doing (setting `location.href`)

Answer (score 0):

You can't really update the href without the page reloading.

You can potentially use history.pushState() or history.replaceState(), but I would be hesitant to take this approach unless you know what you are doing.  If you want to learn more about modify the browsers history I suggest you read the following link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Alternatively, you could append the searchString as an anchor, and make your url something like '/Meeting/Meeting#searchString=yourQuery'.